# sjaakp/yii2-illustrated-behavior Yii2 extension for image not working

Tags: yii2

I am getting error; Is there any complete example of how to use the behavior(configuration in model,view,controller) practically;the documentation on github doesn't really help.

In my model the field that store the img link in db is imglink; the code are:

```php
public $photo;//The file attributes
public function behaviors(){
return [
[
"class" => "sjaakp\illustrated\Illustrated",
"attributes"=>[
'img'=>[
'aspectRatio'=>1.0,
'cropSize'=>90,]
]
],
];
}
//rules : $rules[] = ['photo','file'];
```

in my view :

```php
use sjaakp\illustrated\Uploader;


$this->title = \Yii::t('app','Choose your Profile Photo');
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
        <div id="partiechargee" class="panel panel-default center-block">
            <?php if($titre==true){
             echo '<p class="well-sm">';
           $this->render('/_alert', ['module' => $module,]);
            echo '</p>';}?>

            <h3 class="panel-title panel-heading text-center" style="margin-bottom:5px;"><strong><?= Html::encode($this->title)?></strong></h3>
                <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
                     'id'=> 'form-registration',
                    'enableAjaxValidation'   => true,
                    'enableClientValidation' => false,
                    'method'=>'post',
                    'action'=>\Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['settings/profilephoto']),
                'options'=>['class'=>'well-sm text-center',
                    'enctype'=>'multipart/form-data']]); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'photo')->widget(Uploader::className([ 
        'deleteOptions' => [
            'label' => '<i class="fa fa-trash"></i>',
            'title' => 'Delete image'
        ]
    ])) ?>
  <p class="text-center">
                <?= Html::submitButton(Yii::t('app', 'Exit'), ['class' => 'btn btn-danger cancel btn-block']) ?>
             </p>
                <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

I am getting error : Undefined index: photo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This :

```
public function behaviors(){
return [
[
"class" => "sjaakp\illustrated\Illustrated",
"attributes"=>[
'img'=>[
'aspectRatio'=>1.0,
'cropSize'=>90,]
]
],
];
}
```

Should be:

```
public function behaviors(){
return [
[
"class" => "sjaakp\illustrated\Illustrated",
"attributes"=>[
'photo'//Important to put the attribute of fileinput,
'img'=>[
'aspectRatio'=>1.0,
'cropSize'=>90,]
]
],
];
}
```